# $\mathsf{PP}$ compared to $\mathsf{\#P}$

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request

Since know that $\mathsf{TC^0\subsetneq PP}$, I wonder if we also know that $\mathsf{TC^0\subsetneq\#P}$? I understand that $\mathsf{\#P}$ is in counting hierarchy.

Comment: $\# P$ is not a class of decision problems.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Could problem be given some meaning (with some modification perhaps) since $\mathsf{PP}$ is essentially seeking msb of $\mathsf{\#P}$ problems?